# C++ choose a property to sort by

Tags: c++, object, methods

Assume that I have a class Car with three properties, all of which are `int` type: year, modelNo and topSpeed.

I have a list of Cars, and a function that sorts this list. This method currently sorts the cars by car.modelNo.

If I am going to want to sort by either year, modelNo or topSpeed, I could make three different methods, `sortByYear`, `sortByModelNo` etc.

Is there a way that I can implement one sorting method, and instead just pass it the name of the property I want to sort by? 
So I might call `sortCars(carsList, modelNo);`
Or `sortCars(carsList, year);`

Each of these properties will always be int, and the list will only ever contain Car objects.

Comment: Consider manufacturing [mcve]. It is easier to read, and understand, than descriptions of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using pointers-to-members.

```
void sortCars(std::vector<Car> &cars, int Cars::*property) {
    std::sort(begin(cars), end(cars), [=](Car const &a, Car const &b){
         return (a.*property) < (b.*property);
    });
}
```

Call syntax:

```
sortCars(myCars, &Cars::modelNo);
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard library approach is to pass a functor that implements the desired comparison.  See [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

In this case your `sortCars` function would look something like this:

```
template <typename Comp>
void sortCars(std::vector<Car>& cars, Comp comp)
{
    // compare cars with comp(car1, car2)
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
sortCars(carsList, [](const Car& a, const Car& b) { return a.year < b.year; });
```